# Reputation graph doesn't take the new rep rules into account: apparently, there are different algorithms or caches for different types of reputation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph

There seems to be at least three *different* algos and/or storage/cache spaces for reputation:

1. [The user profile itself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc).
2. [The reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top).
3. [The reputation list](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) (only yours is visible).

In my case, all three shows a different value. As of now, I see the following values:

1. 40,277
2. 36,177 (the latest value of the array in `var d` in JS source, evidently also highest point in graph)
3. 40,253

Noteable is that the graph wasn't updated accordingly during The Big March 2010 Recalc. This inaccuracy by the way also occurs here at Meta, I see respectively 800, 629, 742.

Why is that so? That is counterinituitive to me in developer's perspective. The reputation list seems to be the most reliable source of all. Why isn't all the information derived from the one and the same source? I can imagine of caching reasons, but those differences would mean that there's a *bug* in the code responsible for updating the cached values.

Problems with regard to inaccuracy of the rep graph were [regularly reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation-graph+bug), but they were all taken for non serious, seemingly ignored and/or marked as "by design". How that so? It's clearly a bug.

I also note that one would request a manual recalc for this (mods seem to be capable of this). Doing regulary recalcs is imo not a solution, but a *workaround*.

*Note: I am not concerned about the reputation in general, but more about the **quality** of the sites. To me, this is definitely a bug. Certainly when compared to the relative high-quality remnant of the site.*

Comment: What makes you think that it's showing the old score? Screen shot needed methinks.

Comment: @ChrisF: Rightclick, view source, `Ctrl+F` on `var d` and check the data. It's old.

Comment: @BalusC - I've just come back from doing just that! I lost a couple of hundred points on SO and SU so it's difficult to tell from the graph itself.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache and checking again [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?dummy1) report?

Comment: It's updated realtime and it's already behind since a week or two. First it was 15 points behind, then 14 points, then 24 points. This is also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46026/all-reputation-gone#comment-105512

Comment: @BalusC, /reputation could be some of the question you had answered deleted, but I am agree your original question now, rep graph is quite different, I noticed that, mine is around 900 different too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buggy and confusing rep graph has [finally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go) been killed and there's a [very nice replacement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84754/about-the-replacement-of-the-envelope) which does it *way* better. So, that's already one inaccuracy down the drain.

Left behind the discrepancy between the rep as visible in user profile and the *actual* rep as outlined in deep detail on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation. The *trigger recalc* button at the bottom of that page, which was introduced about half a year ago, makes however a lot up.

---

**Update**: the reputation source inaccuracy has been fixed as per [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).

Answer (score 2):

Rep graph should be mostly accurate, but is still catching up to the /reputation report.

Comment: From developer's perspective, I still don't understand it. Do you mean to say that it's cached?

Comment: `// Documentation missing`

Comment: `// WARNING: SUPER HACK OH GOD HIDE THE CHILDREN`