# Who has hit the highest score hit in a single given day?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, reputation

Just wanted to know for fun who has hit the highest score hit for a single given day? And if possible, how can I determine mine? Thanks.

Comment: Why so many question marks? Also: you should have figured out by now, that greetings in questions are not good practice on these sites.

Comment: The same goes for whining on down-votes.

Comment: @Sarfraz never mind the downvotes. Meta is a ... *special* place :)

Comment: @Pekka, a *harsh*, but *special* place ;-)

Comment: @Andy E that sums it up pretty well. :)

Comment: Plug for my FAQ proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/cletus), 2010-02-04, 754 Δrep
- [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus), 2009-05-26, 747 Δrep
- [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks), 2010-04-26, 619 Δrep

*Disclaimer*: I haven't checked everyone.

Paste the following code into LINQPad:

```
DateTime Zero = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Local);
void Main()
{
    DayReport[] days = null;
    //Hans Passant: 17034
    //Jon Skeet:    22656
    //Marc Gravell: 23354
    //Cletus:       18393
    //Guffa:        69083
    //SLaks:        34397
    //tvanfosson:   12950
    //JaredPar:     23283
    using (var reader = OpenPage(34397)) {
        string line;
        while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) {
            const string repArrayPrefix = "var d = [";

            line = line.Trim();
            if (line.StartsWith("<title>"))
                line.Dump();
            else if(line.StartsWith(repArrayPrefix)) {
                line = line.Substring(repArrayPrefix.Length).TrimEnd(';', ']');

                days = (from s in line.Split(new [] { "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                        let comma = s.IndexOf(',')
                        select new DayReport {
                            Date = Zero.AddMilliseconds(long.Parse(s.Remove(comma).TrimStart('['))),
                            FinalRep = int.Parse(s.Substring(comma + 1).TrimEnd(']'))
                        }).ToArray();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    days[0].DeltaRep = days[0].FinalRep;
    for(int i = 1; i < days.Length; i++) 
        days[i].DeltaRep = days[i].FinalRep - days[i - 1].FinalRep;

    days.OrderByDescending(d => d.DeltaRep).Dump();
}

static StreamReader OpenPage(int userid) {
    using(var wc = new WebClient()) {
        return new StreamReader(wc.OpenRead("https://stackoverflow.com/users/" + userid + "?tab=reputationhistory"));
    }

}

// Define other methods and classes here
class DayReport {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int FinalRep { get; set; } 
    public int DeltaRep { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: With a 615 (2009-08-26) I'm not doing too badly, but I thought Jon had some much bigger numbers. Might want to double-check that...

Comment: @Marc: Feel free to edit in your score.  Jon Skeet consistently gets higher (but not highest) deltas; he probably has more 400's than anyone else.

Comment: Note; the above 615 doesn't show on your query; it might not be reliable for this purpose... I won't edit it in because the 615 is from the rep-report, not this query.

Comment: I've never even hit 300, according to my rep report. Possibly because I don't think I've ever posted more than five answers in a day, and I've never won a bounty on SO.

Comment: @mmyers: Believe it or not, I've never won a bounty either.

Comment: Then that is a jaw-dropping number of accepted answers. What is that, 28 and one downvote? (I've posted 28 answers *since March 17*, but I have slowed quite a bit.)

Comment: SLaks is the fastest gun in the popular tags :) Mine doesn't come above 600. I've two in 500+ range (both feeded by a 250-rep bounty), five in 400+ range, over a quart in 300+ range and for remnant almost all in 200+ range.

Comment: @Slaks great work!

Comment: I got 140 upvotes that day.

Comment: @Marc: this problem may be related to the fact that the datasource of the reputation graph has still to be updated to reflect the "Big Recalc" last March. It are still the old values from before March. Also see [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43609/reputation-graph-doesnt-take-the-new-rep-rules-into-account-apparently-differe).

Comment: According to my current rep report, my best day was June 30th 2009, when I received 755 - but that was including a bounty worth 300.

Comment: Does this include bounties? If yes, my highest score is -- 2010-02-18 rep +870 (from my reputation report).

Answer (score 1):

1. Should be possible by querying the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), but I don't know how to in detail.
2. `www.stackoverflow.com/reputation`

Comment: The data dump won't work with 100% precision because the -1 you get for downvoting aren't available. But close enough.

Comment: I can't figure out where to find that out on dump and which user has the highest.

Comment: @Sarfraz: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema and  http://www.w3schools.com/SQL