# What is the largest "uncapped" reputation gain in SO history?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, data-explorer

I blew it. I hoped the trend of receiving no more than 3 upvotes per question per day would continue. After 43 days, I failed in my goal of trying to reach 10k without hitting the reputation cap. I didn't even hit 3k, which I had hoped I would at least make it that far.

So in honor of my shattered dreams, I thought I'd ask something for those data diggers out there. On each of the websites, what was the largest amount of reputation that someone has earned without ever hitting the reputation cap? Who is still at it? We're talking all <200 gains from day one, not merely the largest amount between two reputation cap hits. I can spend some time and see who still doesn't have the Mortarboard badge for the top users (I know Arjan doesn't, as the lower bound of the top 3 pages of Meta users), but it will never address those who may have made it even further before they finally received the badge.

Comment: someone who got two 550 bounties on the same day?

Comment: @SMark That would address http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48684/ more than the longest uncapped streak.

Comment: This is a more interesting question than who has earned the most in one day.

Comment: Inverse question: lowest rep before being capped. I know I was capped on my first day, and I doubt I was the only one. Anyone fancy checking how many are in the same boat?

Comment: @Jon That... that's not fair! The system recognized your brilliant future from the start? But joking aside, I think the number of people who did cap at day one would also be an interesting query.

Comment: When you say "without ever hitting the reputation cap", is that based on the *new* rules (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) where accepted answers and bounties are immune to the cap? In other words, to technically hit the Rep cap now you have to get, for example, 20 answer upvotes, so you can still get over 200 Rep for a day and not technically hit the cap due to accepted answers and bounties.

Comment: @gnovices I don't know how bounties play into these things currently, but accepted answers count towards "exceeding" the cap, which is enough to get the Mortarboard badge (I received mine at 180 upvote and 30 accept after subtracting some scrambled downvotes to avoid the fate). I would focus on "exceeded", to that end. I don't know how, if at all, bounties play into that.

Comment: data explorer has a bug with the vote table import that kind of makes it hard to calculate, will be sorting it out next data dump (in a few days) and post back with some sort of answer

Comment: @waffles Not to be a bother, but how is the vote table import fix going?

Comment: @ccomet, its already done

Answer (score 5):

For users who still haven't hit the cap:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/192/never-hit-the-rep-cap

Comment: Excellent, now all we need is to do is see if there is anyone who exceeded those numbers before eventually hitting the cap.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at my reputation report on SO, I made it as far as 5890 reputation (2009-11-24) before hitting the cap the next day, taking me to 6120.  I have no idea if that's over or under the average, though.  (On meta, I didn't even make it to 2000, and this happened in the same week as on SO. I recall that that was a slow period at work!)

The easy way to look for this on your own report is to search for the earliest incidence of a number in square brackets (in regexp form, `/\[[/\d+\]]`) indicating an upvote that did not contribute its full value to reputation.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Either a deleted answer or vote fraud discovery changed my previous results, so here are the new ones:

Here are my numbers from SO (found using the [Rep report generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)):

- First time I broke 200 total Rep in one day: 12/7/2009

  ```
    10338 (starting Rep)
  + 245   (+200 votes, +45 accepted answers)
  --------
  = 10583 (final Rep)
  ```

And the very end of my Rep report is kinda confusing...

```
rep cap was reached on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 1 days
```

How exactly can I have never reached it, but exceeded it once? I guess this means that my total Rep gain exceeded 200 but I never actually lost any Rep due to the cap. I guess that's what being active in a niche tag does for you: slow and steady.

So, I guess I've technically managed to tally almost 20,000 Rep thus far without getting capped. I don't know if that's something I should be proud of or not. ;)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it - Jeff gives an explanation in the comments to its only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3481 rep on SO and have never hit the cap.

... but I'm sure others have gotten further.