# My /reputation score and shown rep score are different

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

So I logged into SO this morning and noticed my rep score was a few points higher than yesterday, but I could find no indication of why, so naturally I went to /reputation. and there noticed that my rep score was this.

```
 3   3286270 (-2)
 2   3291010 (5)
 2   3291010 (5)
 2   3291010 (5)
 1   3291027 (2)
 2   3291010 (5)
-- 2010-07-20 rep +20   = 698       
 2   3286270 (10)
-- 2010-07-23 rep +10   = 708       

** total rep 708 :)
```

Yet when I look on SO it is this.
[689 != 708 http://michaelsarchet.com/images/repscore.png](http://michaelsarchet.com/images/repscore.png)

So my question is am I misunderstanding something here or is something up?

***Question that I got rep on today**

[Set linq return property to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286257/3286270#3286270), but no votes, interesting.

Comment: It's by design :( There are different ways where/how the score is saved/calculated/cached. Likely with performance in mind. You can flag a moderator to request for a "recalc". This is likely never going to be solved. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43609/reputation-graph-doesnt-take-the-new-rep-rules-into-account-apparently-there-a

Comment: BTW: you have one upvote and one downvote on that answer. So net score is 0.

Comment: Interesting, so they are all correct and none of them correct then, eh?

Comment: Do you want a recalc right now or would you like to keep it this way for a little while for observation?

Comment: @BalusC and @Grace Note, see now that makes sense, I wish I could see up and down votes on my own answers.

Comment: @msarchet Your displayed score is cached, since it's shown constantly all over the site, but the /reputation score should be accurate

Comment: @mmyers, I'd like to watch it for a bit and see what happens

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, right makes the most sense

Comment: @msarchet: you can instantly see up/downvote totals when you've at least 1000 reputation.

Comment: You can always see the upvotes and downvotes, albeit requiring manual calculation but regardless of reputation, using [the time machine!](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3286257/timeline)

Comment: @Grace: wow, how did you know about that hidden feature? Is it somewhere linked on the question itself?

Comment: @BalusC Jeff had a [big announcement for its testing a month ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54366/feedback-request-newer-timeline-question-view). I don't recall when it ever got pushed to the other sites, but it certainly was. It isn't linked anywhere, you still need to manually enter it.

Comment: @Grace Note, that may be the best thing I've ever seen on SO. @BalusC, I know I'm getting there only 292 more rep to go!

Comment: @Grace: thanks! I should peek a bit more often on Meta than only once a day or two ;)

Comment: @Grace, BalusC, msarchet: There's a [greasemonkey script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40617/a-greasemonkey-script-that-adds-timeline-links-to-all-the-questions) if you use timeline enough to want a link for it

Comment: Thanks for the offer, though I am comfortable with typing it out. @BalusC, on the other hand, I'll ping. ♪

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/reputation` page was created so that you could see what reputation you should have. Sometimes that and your actual reputation don't match due to things like deleted questions, answers and other things in the system that aren't automatically reflected in your current reputation.

If you feel that your `/reputation` number is significantly far off from your actual number, flag one of your posts for moderator attention requesting a reputation recalc. They would be happy to bring those two numbers in line.

Personally, I'm fine if the numbers are off by a little, but when they are off by over 100, I like to get my rep recalculated.

Comment: @Chahca102 these are my sentiments, I just wondered what was going on.

Comment: While email works as suggested here, flagging one of your posts for moderator attention works well (provided you haven't expired all of your posts, at any rate).

Comment: Actually, I'd say flagging is the preferred method. Much quicker and you don't bother the developers unnecessarily.

Comment: don't forget *deleted users* whose votes are also all deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically due to votes on deleted questions and answers, which are accurately reflected on `/reputation` but not on the cached score. A rep-recalc will fix the discrepancy.