# Reputation history on my profile page is inconsistent with /reputation log

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My /reputation score and shown rep score are different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58264/my-reputation-score-and-shown-rep-score-are-different)

This is the screenshot of [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648313/idolon?tab=reputation) taken on 2011-12-06 (so "today" means Dec 6, and "yesterday" - Dec 5). Note the "**0  Dec 2**" section:

[image: reputation screenshot taken on 2011-12-06]

And this is the part of my https://stackoverflow.com/reputation list:

```
 2   7714302 (5)
 2   7807520 (10)
-- 2011-11-30 rep +15   = 2360      
 1   8135366 (15)
-- 2011-12-02 rep +15   = 2375      
-- 2011-12-04 rep 0     = 2375      
 2   8384617 (10)
-- 2011-12-05 rep +10   = 2385      
 2   7607705 (10)
 2   6739936 (10)
-- 2011-12-06 rep +20   = 2405
```

Here on **Dec 2** we can see **+15** reputation change, and **rep 0** is present on **Dec 4** instead.

**UPDATE**

I triggered the "rep recalc" as @ChrisF has suggested, but nothing has changed, thus I assume there IS a bug in the reputation visualization on the profile page and this question should be reopened.

I read " [My /reputation score and shown rep score are different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58264/158912) " and don't think this question could be classified as a duplicate of that one. Here I describe not the difference of the summary rating values but rather the desynchronization between rep. audit and profile reputation histories which IS NOT fixed by "rep recalc" click.

Comment: @NickCraver Can you please review my flag on this post?

Comment: underneath it's the same issue, just not from the UI view...trust me we're very much working on this, we have huge underlying changes here to improve the reputation system, not something you'll see much other than all of these sync and display issues going away, stay tuned.

Comment: @NickCraver Thx for the quick reply. Glad to hear you're improving the reputation system. If it's going to fix sync/display issues, then there's really no need for me to reopen this question - I just wanted to be sure you're aware of the issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is the "truth", the former is cached.

The `reputation` page takes into account post deletion the profile page doesn't always - depending on when the post was deleted.

Do a recalculation and the former should match the latter.

Comment: So the cached version on the profile page may show "Dec 4, rep 0" on the different day, not show "Dec 2, rep +15" at all, but still display correct reputation summary value? Did I take it right?

Comment: @Idolon- something like that. It will depend on the actual actions. You could have had an acceptance removed for example which might show on a different day in your profile until you recalculate. In all these cases the history presented in `/reputation` is the correct one.

Comment: OK, I've done the reputation recalc, but nothing changed. Will it take some time to update the reputation on the profile page?

Comment: @Idolon - probably. I'd give it a few hours.

Comment: 7 hours has passed and [nothing changed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/648313/idolon?tab=reputation) so far, can we assume now there IS a bug?