# Reputation leagues bug in "Top New Users"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-leagues

If you go [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/), you'll see on your right:

[image]

All of which were not previously ranked; so they all gained their current reputation in this month. How come the "+x reputation this month" value is lower than their current rep? This also affects other ranges (year, quarter, week (?))

Comment: I originally figured this may have had to do with reputation discrepancies a la audit. Some people have accurate, while some people have more than their shown (the new image, for example, sled is accurate). The fact is, though, discrepancy is far more prevalent than it should be, especially in the new sites, so I'm not so sure it's due to that anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this is happening.

The first, larger number (in black) is the user's *current* reputation. The second number (with the "+" and in green) is the from the last time the league was updated (eg: every day around 0:00 GMT).

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly caused by deleted questions/answers whose up/downvote did affect your reputation. They get recalculated correctly in `/reputation` and the API, but for the user rep (as shown in *flair*) it only happens for the day of today and for rep graph it don't happen at all. At least, that's my observation.

If you request the moderator for a recalc, then the reputation as shown in *flair* will match the one as shown in `/reputation`. You can request it by flagging an arbitrary post of yourself or leaving a mail at team@stackoverflow.

Related: [Rep graph not accurate, there are apparently different algorithms/caches for reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43609/reputation-graph-doesnt-take-the-new-rep-rules-into-account-apparently-there-a)